# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to create MD5 hash for file content

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
<a href="openFile:F:/AS_Pro/Grocehopper/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath&#39;: Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.">Show Details</a>
```

When i click on open file or show details nothing happens.Below are all my dependencies

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dev.app.grocehop"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'){
        exclude group:'com.android.support'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

I am not able to resolve which file is giving me this error.

I have gone through several pages but none of them provided me a resolution.
I am very desperate to complete this android project and the error just seems to not go.

Please any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the complete error stack?

Comment: It just shows this. No further details are provided.

Comment: @Bsquare when i click on 'open file' it just opens up the above dependencies file. My previous other files are compiling fine,only when i try to create a new project this error shows up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you need to add third party library dependency on your new project?